# how to disentangle the influence of two correlated dummy variables

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data

I am analyzing the effect of two factors on performance in an easily measured test. The two independent variables are "category" variables, let's call them "strategy" and "manager". Each test result is assigned to a single manager and a single strategy. There are 106 managers and they can choose among 18 strategies. Manager and strategy are somewhat correlated; certain managers favor certain strategies, though no manager limits himself to only one.

The dataset includes hundreds of test results and their associated manager and strategy.  If the managers and strategies have been translated to unique integers, this can be represented as a list that looks like {{12, 15, 0.0951909}, {43, 11, 0.078721}, {112, 11, -0.520077}, etc.}

What is the best technique for determining the degree to which the test result varies with manager and strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what analysis of variance (ANOVA) is created for. In particular, you should use a [two-way ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_analysis_of_variance) that

> examines the influence of two different categorical independent variables on one continuous dependent variable

This can be easily done with SPSS or R. Ideally, you would also test for interaction effects if the main effects are significant.

Comment: Thanks. The data violates some ANOVA assumptions but this approach may be as good as I'm going to be able to do.